# Count how many different countries are in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
   ID  country 
    -------------
    1       US            
    2       Japan           
    3       China           
    4       US          
    5       China
```

How can one query the table, so that it returns how many different countries are in the table (i.e 3)?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) [Have you read the docs?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/)

Comment: For your updated question: Use a where join :) It would have been good if you sticked to the original question only (one question at a time).

Comment: hi @Mario, welcome to SO. If you have another question please [ask one!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). By changing this one you invalidate all the current answers, which defeats the purpose of Stack Overflow. You may also find you get a better quality of answer and that people are more willing to help you if you are able to demonstrate that you have [tried something for yourself](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following SQL query will result in counting the number of unique countries in your table.

```
select  count(distinct country)
from    YourTable
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to select the amount of unique countries. This is done by selecting all country entries, which are then grouped so there is only one country entry per country name.

`SELECT count(country) from countrytable group by country;`

This is basically the same as Andomars answer.

Comment: why group by when distinct is more efficient

Answer (score 2):

you can use this

```
SELECT country, COUNT( id ) 
   FROM [table_name] GROUP BY country
   LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Output :

```
 country count(id) 
---------------------
 US       2            
 Japan    1           
 china    2
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT count(distinct country) from countrytable

Comment: I guess the distinct country doesn't help here, because the countries are already grouped and distinct is only another shortcut for group by?

Comment: You either need distinct OR group by, not both.

Answer (score 0):

select  count(distinct country)
from    table1

```
 SELECT count( DISTINCT country )
 FROM table1 c
 WHERE c.item_id = (
 SELECT main_id
 FROM table2
 WHERE main_id = c.item_id )
```

Answer (score 0):

select count(distinct country)
from [TableName]

Comment: Your answers must include extra information or some insights than what already is mentioned in other people's answer.